# Google Chrome extension that can open all selected links

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can open all selected links in new tabs.

I am aware of the Google Chrome extension [Linky](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linky/bknechokhjgchpodgplolmkgicojmgnd?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) but it doesn't work anymore.

Example (using  Linky when it used to work):

[image]

Any price, license or operating system is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  [Linkclump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj) (free). It allows to open multiple links in new tabs with right-dragging:

[image]

Comment: I used to use this for a while but it stopped working now. Is there another alternative that is still working?